# Pandas Mean Axis Argument

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, row, mean

I have a dataset of such form:

```
+--------+---+---------+--------+-------+-------+-------+
|            |  A      |  B     |   C   |   D   |   E   |
+------------+---------+--------+-------+-------+-------+
|      0     | 1       | 2      |   3   |   4   |   AB  |
+------------+---------+--------+-------+-------+-------+
```

I want to compute the mean value of the rows values between B to D. So for row 0 will be:

```
B+C+D/(3) = 3
```

How can I do that?

Comment: `df.loc[:, 'B':'D'].mean(axis=1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.mean(axis=1)` on the selected columns. Adding `axis=1` means it will be applied on horizontal axis, or row-wise:

```
a = {'A':[1],'B':[2],'C':[3],'D':[4],'E':['AE']}
df = pd.DataFrame(a)
cols = ['B','C','D']
df['Average'] = df[cols].mean(axis=1)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   A  B  C  D   E  Average
0  1  2  3  4  AE      3.0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`df.mean`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mean.html)

`df.loc[:, "b":"d"].mean(axis=1)`

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({"a": [1, 2], "b": [2, 3], "c": [3, 4], "d": [4, 5], "e": list("AB")})

df["s"] = df.loc[:, "b":"d"].mean(axis=1)
```

Outputs:

```
Out[12]:    a  b  c  d  e    s
         0  1  2  3  4  A  3.0
         1  2  3  4  5  B  4.0
```